# Random Delay When Printing to Dymo LabelWriter Turbo Via ShellExecute()

Tags: c++, c++builder, shellexecute

I have an external program which takes in a few arguments (PrintLabel) which is called from my application using ShellExecute. PrintLabel is shown below. Sometimes it can take upwards to 15 to 20 seconds to print a label. It seems to get worse over time. If the PC is rebooted, then the printing speeds up again but it gets slower over time. Sometimes it is random (i.e. fast then slow). I am using SW_HIDE because I do not want the user to see the console dialog box everytime. I understand it should take a few seconds like a normal printer would, but 15 - 20 seconds seems excessive. Is it a Dymo LabelWriter issue or ShellExecute issue? ShellExecute is called within the UI thread. Any clues?

ShellExecute statement from application:

```
ShellExecute(Application->Handle, "open", "C:\\Program Files\\Application\\PrintLabel", objdata, "C:\\Program Files\\Application", SW_HIDE);
```

PrintLabel Code:

...

```
m_DymoAddIn.Print2(Copies, false, Tray);
```

...

Here is the CDymoAddIn4.h:

```
// Machine generated IDispatch wrapper class(es) created with Add Class from Typelib Wizard

// CDymoAddIn4 wrapper class

class CDymoAddIn4 : public COleDispatchDriver
{
public:
    CDymoAddIn4(){} // Calls COleDispatchDriver default constructor
    CDymoAddIn4(LPDISPATCH pDispatch) : COleDispatchDriver(pDispatch) {}
    CDymoAddIn4(const CDymoAddIn4& dispatchSrc) : COleDispatchDriver(dispatchSrc) {}

    // Attributes
public:

    // Operations
public:


    // IDymoAddIn4 methods
public:
    BOOL Open(LPCTSTR FileName)
    {
        BOOL result;
        static BYTE parms[] = VTS_BSTR ;
        InvokeHelper(0x1, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BOOL, (void*)&result, parms, FileName);
        return result;
    }
    BOOL Save()
    {
        BOOL result;
        InvokeHelper(0x2, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BOOL, (void*)&result, NULL);
        return result;
    }
    BOOL SaveAs(LPCTSTR FileName)
    {
        BOOL result;
        static BYTE parms[] = VTS_BSTR ;
        InvokeHelper(0x3, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BOOL, (void*)&result, parms, FileName);
        return result;
    }
    BOOL Print(long Copies, BOOL bShowDialog)
    {
        BOOL result;
        static BYTE parms[] = VTS_I4 VTS_BOOL ;
        InvokeHelper(0x4, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BOOL, (void*)&result, parms, Copies, bShowDialog);
        return result;
    }
    void Hide()
    {
        InvokeHelper(0x5, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, NULL);
    }
    void Show()
    {
        InvokeHelper(0x6, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, NULL);
    }
    void SysTray(BOOL State)
    {
        static BYTE parms[] = VTS_BOOL ;
        InvokeHelper(0x7, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, parms, State);
    }
    void Quit()
    {
        InvokeHelper(0x8, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, NULL);
    }
    CString get_FileName()
    {
        CString result;
        InvokeHelper(0x9, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, VT_BSTR, (void*)&result, NULL);
        return result;
    }
    BOOL SelectPrinter(LPCTSTR Printer)
    {
        BOOL result;
        static BYTE parms[] = VTS_BSTR ;
        InvokeHelper(0xa, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BOOL, (void*)&result, parms, Printer);
        return result;
    }
    CString GetDymoPrinters()
    {
        CString result;
        InvokeHelper(0xb, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BSTR, (void*)&result, NULL);
        return result;
    }
    CString GetMRULabelFiles()
    {
        CString result;
        InvokeHelper(0x12d, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BSTR, (void*)&result, NULL);
        return result;
    }
    BOOL Open2(LPCTSTR FileName)
    {
        BOOL result;
        static BYTE parms[] = VTS_BSTR ;
        InvokeHelper(0x12e, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BOOL, (void*)&result, parms, FileName);
        return result;
    }
    long GetMRULabelFileCount()
    {
        long result;
        InvokeHelper(0x12f, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_I4, (void*)&result, NULL);
        return result;
    }
    CString GetMRULabelFileName(long Index)
    {
        CString result;
        static BYTE parms[] = VTS_I4 ;
        InvokeHelper(0x130, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BSTR, (void*)&result, parms, Index);
        return result;
    }
    BOOL OpenMRULabelFile(long Index)
    {
        BOOL result;
        static BYTE parms[] = VTS_I4 ;
        InvokeHelper(0x131, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BOOL, (void*)&result, parms, Index);
        return result;
    }
    BOOL OpenMRULabelFileByName(LPCTSTR FileName)
    {
        BOOL result;
        static BYTE parms[] = VTS_BSTR ;
        InvokeHelper(0x132, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BOOL, (void*)&result, parms, FileName);
        return result;
    }
    BOOL Print2(long Copies, BOOL bShowDlg, long Tray)
    {
        BOOL result;
        static BYTE parms[] = VTS_I4 VTS_BOOL VTS_I4 ;
        InvokeHelper(0x191, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BOOL, (void*)&result, parms, Copies, bShowDlg, Tray);
        return result;
    }
    long GetCurrentPaperTray()
    {
        long result;
        InvokeHelper(0x192, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_I4, (void*)&result, NULL);
        return result;
    }
    void StartPrintJob()
    {
        InvokeHelper(0xc9, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, NULL);
    }
    void EndPrintJob()
    {
        InvokeHelper(0xca, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, NULL);
    }
    BOOL IsTwinTurboPrinter(LPCTSTR PrinterName)
    {
        BOOL result;
        static BYTE parms[] = VTS_BSTR ;
        InvokeHelper(0xcb, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BOOL, (void*)&result, parms, PrinterName);
        return result;
    }
    CString GetCurrentPrinterName()
    {
        CString result;
        InvokeHelper(0xce, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BSTR, (void*)&result, NULL);
        return result;
    }

    // IDymoAddIn4 properties
public:

};
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with all the technologies you are using, but what the hey, I'll comment anyway. It looks like you've posted a lot of boilerplate code that does little or nothing. The meat of the console app you've got there seems to be m_DymoAddIn.Print2( Copies, false, Tray); where Copies and Tray are just ints. But you don't show us the code for class CDymoAddIn4, which m_DymoAddIn is an instance of. That's kind of important! Just as a wild guess - does that class have a Flush() type method to immediately empty the internal buffers and send the data ?

Comment: I can't remember - are you calling StartPrintJob() and in particular EndPrintJob() ? (Maybe you can put back the old code - it would be nice if all the boilerplate comments etc. were omitted but actually that's not a biggie :-)

Comment: No, I am not using Start/End Print Job

Comment: Maybe that's something to try - it matches your symptoms - Sometimes when you send data to a system it will assume you are going to send more and just cache the data - you need a way to say hey I'm done let's do this thing. But of course I'm just speculating. Good luck. My final bit of meta-advice is to make sure you keep experimenting - and try to reduce your problem to the smallest example possible to de-clutter your mind and focus on a minimal set of problem elements.

Comment: Your advice I think is where the problem lies... It is not with ShellExecute() but possibly with the Dymo Interface. I looked through the Dymo SDK some more and here is a comment from the sample code:  

// ATTENTION: This call is very important if you're making mutiple calls to the Print() or Print2() function!
It's a good idea to always wrap StartPrintJob() and EndPrintJob() around a call to Print() or Print2() function.

Comment: There you go. I hope you don't mind, I'll copy and paste to an actual answer so you can give me an upvote!

Comment: I am out of votes for the next four hours.. I will have to come back later and upvote.

Comment: Thanks. Good luck with your project, hope it all works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add calls to StartPrintJob() and EndPrintJob(). Sometimes when you send data to a system it will assume you are going to send more and just cache the data - you need a way to say hey I'm done let's do this thing.

And a bit of meta-advice - Make sure you keep experimenting - and try to reduce your problem to the smallest example possible to de-clutter your mind and focus on a minimal set of problem elements

(See comments to Question for genesis of this Answer)

Answer (score 0):

How many labels are printed before the issue arises?  Could this be a memory/handle leak that is causing printing to slow down?  Are you freeing all COM objects properly? Have you checked resource usage with ProcessExplorer or Task Manager?

Comment: You could also try to enable CodeGuard in C++Builder to check for leaks.

Comment: It takes about fifty labels before it gets worse and then it is downhill from there.